# TypeScript refuses to allow jQuery 'on' wiring

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript on my site now, and am having a difficult time with a specific jQuery event.

For the sake of example, I am shortening my code to just the relevant parts; I have it setup like this...

```
var elements = {
   wizard: {}
};

elements.wizard.wizard({ // initialization behavior // });
elements.wizard.on('step-shown', function(e){
   // do some stuff here
});
```

Wizard is declared like this;

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.wizard = function(options) {
      // behavior of wizard plugin
   }
})(jQuery);
```

And then I have the Typescript definition for it ...

```
interface JQuery {
   Wizard(options);
}
```

I am able to actually wire the wizard itself up, but this isn't my issue. The issue is the `on` part, it says that `property 'on' does not exist on type '{}'`. I am not sure how to handle this, though. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not declaring the wizard variable of the type `JQuery.Wizard`.

In your code

```
var elements = {
   wizard: {}
};

elements.wizard.wizard({ // initialization behavior // });
elements.wizard.on('step-shown', function(e){
   // do some stuff here
});
```

Wizard is instantiated as an empty object `{}`, hence it has no methods or variables. That is why you are receiving the errors.

Instead of typing it as `any` or a custom type, simply type it to the `JQuery.Wizard` type.

```
var elements = {
   wizard: <JQuery.Wizard>{}
};

elements.wizard.wizard({ // initialization behavior // });
elements.wizard.on('step-shown', function(e){
   // do some stuff here
});
```

I demonstrated the behaviour on [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Wizard%20%7B%0A%09aProperty?%3a%20number;%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20elements%20=%20%7B%0A%20%20%20anUntypedWizard%3a%20%7B%7D,%0A%20%20%20aTypedWizard%3a%20%3CWizard%3E%7B%7D%0A%7D;%0A%0Aalert%28elements.anUntypedWizard.aProperty%29;%0Aalert%28elements.aTypedWizard.aProperty%29;).

Comment: Trying to do this gives me a strange error; It tells me that it expects `,` instead of `.` on anything I try.

Comment: That is, in the actual `<JQuery.Wizard>` part. It also does this if I try more professionally defined types, like anything in the kendo suite.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you running?

Comment: To my knowledge it is the newest, I just downloaded it a few days ago.

Comment: I solved it. It was my own fault. I was declaring it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of type inference. When you say:

```
var elements = {
   wizard: {}
};
```

TypeScript infers that elements has member wizard, and wizard has no further members (because of `{}`)

One option is to use `any`:

```
var elements = {
   wizard: <any>{}
};
```

or your custom type:

```
var elements = {
   wizard: <whatyouactuallythinkthisshouldbe>{}
};
```